# How to change from kali linux to ubuntu with a pendrive

Tags: system-installation

I used a program to turn de iso file to some folders and archives, including one that is named: wubi.exe which is the one i should run to start the installation, but I cant run that program in linux. What should I do?
Please tell me how would you change from a kali to an ubuntu!

Comment: You have to install Ubuntu like you would with any other OS. The best choice is probably from a LiveCD or LiveUSB.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, changing between versions of Linux is not as simple as just running an executable. You need to put the downloaded ISO onto a USB with something like Unetbootin and do a fresh install, however if you keep the same username and password as well as computer name it should preserve the files in your home folder.